# FAIL: qt/test/test_bitcoin-qt.exe when running 'make' after building Bitcoin Core 26.99.0

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, windows, functional-test

I'm building Bitcoin Core 26.99 following this:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-windows.md

I'm using this option for building Bitcoin Core on Windows:
Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and Mingw-w64.

When I ran "make check", I got the full error below:

```
Making check in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/amaluenda/bitcoin/src'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/amaluenda/bitcoin/src'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/amaluenda/bitcoin'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/amaluenda/bitcoin'
  GEN      obj/build.h
make  minisketch/test.exe
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/amaluenda/bitcoin/src'
make[3]: 'minisketch/test.exe' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/amaluenda/bitcoin/src'
make  check-TESTS check-local
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/amaluenda/bitcoin/src'
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/amaluenda/bitcoin/src'
PASS: minisketch/test.exe
PASS: univalue/test/object.exe
PASS: univalue/test/unitester.exe
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/amaluenda/bitcoin'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/amaluenda/bitcoin'
  GEN      obj/build.h
FAIL: qt/test/test_bitcoin-qt.exe
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for Bitcoin Core 26.99.0
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 4
# PASS:  3
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  1
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
See src/test-suite.log
Please report to https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues
============================================================================
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/amaluenda/bitcoin/src'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/amaluenda/bitcoin/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/amaluenda/bitcoin/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/amaluenda/bitcoin/src'
```

And here's the src/test-suite.log:

```
==============================================
   Bitcoin Core 26.99.0: src/test-suite.log
==============================================

# TOTAL: 4
# PASS:  3
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  1
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0

.. contents:: :depth: 2

FAIL: qt/test/test_bitcoin-qt
=============================

FAIL qt/test/test_bitcoin-qt.exe (exit status: 2)
```

Will someone be so kind as to please help me resolve this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This question may be better suited for a GitHub issue, given that it is failing a unit test, which usually indicates an issue with the code, rather than how the person asking the question is using it.